# How could I make a Proof Assistant?

Tags: recommendations, creation

If, as a complete beginner, I wanted to create a proof assistant, how would I begin to start this? How easy is one to create? What advice do you have?

---

###### Note: contains "multiple questions" as it is asking for an overview "umbrella" answer.

Comment: I think that the question is legal to Proof Assistants even with 3 questionable sentences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many good resources, such as *the little prover* book, ["A tutorial implementation
of a dependently typed lambda calculus"](https://www.andres-loeh.de/LambdaPi/LambdaPi.pdf) tutorial, ["A simple type-theoretic language: Mini-TT"](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Ebengt/papers/GKminiTT.pdf) tutorial, etc..

My take on this question is that you first need to study and understand how to use (maybe various different styles of) proof assistants. There are proof assistants based on dependent type theory (Lean, Coq, etc.), some exotic type theories (Arend, cooltt, etc.), simple type theory (Isabelle), set theory (Mizar), and others. Make sure what kind of base theory you would like to implement, and then checkout relevant resources. The three tutorials I mentioned at the beginning are all about dependent types.

To start with a dependent-type one, you'd better get familiar with writing lambda calculus interpreters (including parsers and pretty printers) and debugging these interpreters. This is highly nontrivial, as you'll see there will be many different techniques are involved, like index notations or hoas. I strongly recommend you to get *very experienced* in writing interpreters and software engineering, because proof assistants are extremely sophisticated programs.

Then, you'll implement the type checker, which is the most sophisticated part of a proof assistant based on type theory. Optionally (well, most likely) you'll implement a tactic system, which is a popular tool for constructing proofs. For that you can checkout *the little prover* book I mentioned above.

For other styles, I don't know much, so I'll leave it to other potential answerers :D

For research literature, you may find WITS, TyDe, ICFP, POPL, JFP, ESOP, (in random order) and other venues helpful.

Comment: I'd be interested about how to add custom datatypes into LambdaPi. I tried it myself few times without success.

Comment: @Cheery what do you mean by custom datatypes? Like inductive types like in Agda/Idris/Coq/Lean? That's very complex, and probably cannot be covered by simple tutorials. (Maybe I'll write one, as I've implemented that myself (not very confident on correctness tho))